# How to use Icons like Font Awesome in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I want to use Font Awesome Icons in my Gatsby project. I would love to include font awesome with a CDN.

Just including it in a script tag doesn't work.  I think I need to import it with `import ... from '../fontawesome.css'` but i am not able to get this working and also wanted to use a cdn for that. Or do I need to parse it with a css library for gatsby?

Please give me advice or hints how to do it.

Comment: "Just including it in a script tag doesn't work."  Hard to help with code we can't see.

Comment: Use react-icons instead

Answer (score 91, accepted):

For anyone visiting this page in late 2018+, I would highly recommend using [react-icons](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons).

```
import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa';

class Question extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h3> Lets go for a <FaBeer />? </h3>
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely the easiest way.

Comment: Simple and Perfect!

Comment: @sntnupi: using this method, how do I access the unicode value of the icons in CSS.
code: ```&:after { content: '\f0f2'; font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';``` } does not work.

Comment: Just tried out react-icons. It looks like the perfect solution at first glance, but seems to be outdated/unsupported. It may work just fine for some, though, so worth a try. It did not include some of the font awesome icons I wanted to use, though.

Answer (score 12):

It's better to include every module that your application needs in just one JS. But if you still want to use CDN, just copy and edit the default template:

```
cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js
```

If you want to pack font-awesome in the project bundle, you may choose:

- Use some react icon library. e.g. [react-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome)
- Include the CSS files

For the last option, you must move the css and fonts in pages folder and then include fa in your js file.

```
import './css/font-awesome.css'
```

To use a font-awesome class, use the className attribute

```
<i className="fa fa-twitter"></i>
```

If you are looking get the js code from a CDN, use [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com)

Comment: https://github.com/gorangajic/react-icons is another option containing the icons from the Font Awesome, Material Design, Github Octicons, Ionicons and Typicons libraries.

Comment: Note that even `react-fontawesome` still requires you to link to or include the CSS files in some way. To quote from their NPM page: "Note: This component does not include any of the Font Awesome CSS or fonts, so you'll need to make sure to include those on your end somehow, either by adding them to your build process or linking to CDN versions." So it isn't really a choice - `react-fontawesome` only handles react component logic

Answer (score 11):

Here is the **recommended** way to use **Font-Awesome** icons in Gatsby:

Add the following code snippet (mentioned in official [react-fontawesome docs](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome)) in your higher components like `Layout` or `Page`.

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee  } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(fab, faCheckSquare, faCoffee)
```

> First `npm install -S` and `import` free-brands-svg-icons or/ and free-solid-svg-icons only if you need icons from them.

Then in each component where to use icons, add the following code:

`import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome"`

Now use it in your component like shown below:

`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", "apple"]} style={{color:"#000000"}} />`

> I believe it is at this step where things go wrong. You need to include 'fab' in `icon` prop as shown above if you are adding brand icons. Otherwise if using (let say) solid icons, then just enter the spinal-case (e.g check-square) styled name of the icon without [] enclosing brackets in `icon` prop instead of camelCase (checkSquare) and you don't need to include 'fa' in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to last comment.
The reason you need to pass an `array` to `icon` prop is because the default prefix used in FontAwesomeIcon component is `fas`. So if you supply icon from `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons` (e.g. faHome) you don't need to add prefix.

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={home} />
```

For all other packages as e.g. `'@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'` you have to supply array to icon specifying prefix

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", "laravel"]} />
```

Also, nice to know thing, is that you DON'T need to import all `fab` icons into your library. Same like with solid icons ('fas') you can import just icons you need and then just add them to library.
Something like:

```
// fab icon (brand)    
import { faLaravel } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons"
// fas icon (solid)
import { faHome } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
library.add(faHome, faLaravel)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add font-awesome script in **layout.js** <**Helmet**> tag:

```
<Helmet>
    <html lang={site.lang} />
    <link
        rel="shortcut icon"
        type="image/x-icon"
        href={Favicon}
    ></link>
    {/* adding google fonts */}
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat" rel="stylesheet"/>
    {/* adding font-awesome icons */}
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/02130b3d51.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style type="text/css">{`${site.codeinjection_styles}`}</style>
    <body className={bodyClass} />
</Helmet>
```

Now add simply, the font-awesome icons where ever you like:

```
<h2 onClick={scrollToBottom} style={buttonStyle} className="scroll-btn" aria-label="to bottom" component="span">
    {/* adding font-awesome icon */}
    <i className="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i>
</h2>
```

It's really this simple!!